# How to make a Gradient in CAGradientLayer follow a certain value on a slider?

Tags: swift4, xcode9, uislider, cagradientlayer

How can i change the gradient layer in CAGradient layer to be able to see where a certain value starts on a slider just by looking at the color of the CAGradient layer that is placed on the slider? This is my code this far...

```
func sliderValueDidChange(slider:[UISlider]) {
    for index in 0...slider.count - 1 {
        let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Double(slider[index].bounds.width), height: 5)
        tgl.frame = frame


        tgl.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]


        tgl.borderWidth = 0.5
        tgl.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        tgl.cornerRadius = 2.5




        tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0)
        tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0)



        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        slider[index].setMaximumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 0.5, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)), for:.normal)
        slider[index].setMinimumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero), for:.normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solve this by taking the Certain value and splitting it with the maximum value of the slider so you get a percentage of the slider. Then you use this as location of the gradientLayer like this

```
func sliderValueDidChange(slider:UISlider) {
    var floatNumberOne = Float()
    var floatNumberTwo = Float()
    var numbersOne = [NSNumber]()
    var splitTwo = [Float()]
    var valueYouWhantTheFirstGradientToEndAt = 130
    var valueYouWhantTheSecondGradientToEndAt = 170


    floatNumberOne = Float(valueYouWhantTheFirstGradientToEndAt)
    floatNumberTwo = Float(valueYouWhantTheSecondGradientToEndAt)


    var split = scaleSplit(numberOne: floatNumberOne, numberTwo: floatNumberTwo)




    print(floatNumberOne, floatNumberTwo)



    numbersOne.append(split[0] as! NSNumber)
    numbersOne.append(split[1] as! NSNumber)




    print(numbersOne)





        let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Double(slider.bounds.width), height: 5)

        tgl.frame = frame

        tgl.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]


        tgl.borderWidth = 0.5
        tgl.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        tgl.cornerRadius = 2.5


        tgl.locations = numbersOne



        tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0)
        tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0)



        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        slider.setMaximumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 0.5, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)), for:.normal)
        slider.setMinimumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero), for:.normal)




}
func scaleSplit(numberOne: Float, numberTwo:Float)->[Float]{
    var splitter = [Float]()
    var splitterOne = Float()
    var splitterTwo = Float()

    splitterOne = numberOne/Float(maxValueOfSlider)
    spliterTwo = numberTwo/Float(maxValueOfSlider)



    splitter = [splitterOne, splitterTwo]

    return splitter
}
```